# get place within the given lat and long in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am in a trouble to find the places within the lat, long and radius using ajax or javascript , i used a ajax code to find this but getting error, 
my code is :

```
   $.ajax({ url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?',
      data: {
        location:'-33.8670522,151.1957362',
        radius:500,
       sensor:false,
      key:'AIzaSyAImBQiqvaXOQtqeK8VC-9I96kMmB6Mz7I'},
     dataType: "json",
     type: "GET", //or POST if you want => update your php in that case
      success: function( data ) {
     for(var i in data.results){
       alert(data.results[i]);
     }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
     alert("error");
    //handle errors
   }
    });
```

it gets the result error, please help me to find this

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure google API doesn't support json because it exposes your api-key in the client-side view, thus making the actual security feature 100% useless for anyone that wants to make chaos. That being said, you can use a server side controller that makes the request and sends it back to the client. You can still use ajax, just need a server inbetween.

Comment: Then I'll stand corrected, as I said, was pretty sure, not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code to get places from near by locations

```
function initialize(arg)
    {        


        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        mapmarker="img/pois/"+arg+".png";
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(11.21989,78.16811099999995);
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              center: location,
              zoom: 15
            });

          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


          var request = {
            location: location,
            radius: '5000',
            types: [arg]
          };
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    }


    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function callback(results, status) 
    {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
          {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
          var place = results[i];
          createMarker(results[i]);


        }
          }
    }
```